# How to take a subset of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, subset

What I'd like is this:

```
>>> [i if i!= 0 for i in [0,1,2,3]]
[1,2,3]
```

just like

```
>>> [i for i in [1,2,3,4]]
[1,2,3,4]
```

What's the simple solution that doesn't yield a syntax error?

Edit: assuming I don't want to use a for loop and appending all elements to a new list.

Comment: if comes later: `[i for i in [0,1,2,3] if i!= 0 ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [i for i in [0,1,2,3] if i!=0] to get

[1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

You can add `if` at the end:

```
[i for i in [0,1,2,3] if i!= 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `if i != 0` at the end of the list comprehension, like this:

```
[i for i in [0,1,2,3] if i!=0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in [0,1,2,3] if 1 != 0]
```